# Import statement is breaking down application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im trying to import a mongoose model from one file containing the schema (`issue.js`) to another file (`server.js`). i am running the app with nodemon and all works well until i try to import the Issue model from the `issue.js` file into the `server.js` file, nodemon then logs a message saying

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

referring to the model in the import statement

Ive tried implementing different types of import statements and

here is my "issue model" and export statement in issue.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Issue = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    responsible: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    severity: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Open'
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('Issue', Issue);
```

and here is where i try to import it into server.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

import Issue from './models/Issue.js';
```

when i save the server.js file with the import statement nodemon restarts the application and crashes with the console message

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

in reference to the Issue import. 
Is there something that i am missing here about the syntax of these import and export statements?

Comment: can you add your mongoose import to the question?

Comment: Which version of node? I think it supports es6 import since v12. Otherwise you need to compile.

Comment: currently up to date on v12.3.1. What do you mean by compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use imports you need to config it in Babel. A quick fix is to use the common JS system

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Issue = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    responsible: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    severity: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Open'
    }
});

module.exports ={ mongoose.model('Issue', Issue);}
```

and then

```
const Issue = require('./models/Issue.js')
```

for import